# Weird blank window in Task switcher (User Information?)

Tags: windows-10, desktop, task-switching

I've noticed, at several occasions, that while I do not have any active applications running, if I press Alt-Tab for the task switcher - and against any expectations, there is a blank window there:

[image: windows 10 task switch blank window]

Sometimes, when I reboot after I've seen this window, I get that "User Information" process is preventing reboot.

This is my Windows version:

```
C:\>systeminfo

Host Name:                 DESKTOP-MMXXXXX
OS Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Home
OS Version:                10.0.18363 N/A Build 18363
OS Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
OS Configuration:          Standalone Workstation
OS Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free
```

Would anyone have an idea, why does this window show up in Task Switcher - and how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `tasklist /v` in a command prompt to see if you can identify the window title and thus the exe file. **If** "User Information" is the window it should be apparent.

If that doesn't help try `winlist` from https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2019/05/winlistexe-list-open-windows-and-their.html and see if that identifies the exe file.